# VSCode "go to definition" does not work in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code

Mainly what the title says, while I can run "go to definition" command on "main.py" python scripts, I am unable to make the same command run on jupyter notebooks.

I have tried using Jedi, but currently are using PyLance. VSCode is updated, and I have tried using pre-release versions as well.

Anyone has a robust way to solve this other than using PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary suggestion, in the meantime you can use the IPython built-in [magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) to get the function signature and location inside the notebook and then get to the desired file location (and function definition) that way. For example running `??np.einsum` (aka the `%pinfo2` command) in a cell will output:

```
Signature:  np.einsum(*operands, out=None, optimize=False, **kwargs)
Source:   
@array_function_dispatch(_einsum_dispatcher, module='numpy')
def einsum(*operands, out=None, optimize=False, **kwargs):
    """
    einsum(subscripts, *operands, out=None, dtype=None, order='K',
           casting='safe', optimize=False)

    Evaluates the Einstein summation convention on the operands.

    Using the Einstein summation convention, many common multi-dimensional,
    linear algebraic array operations can be represented in a simple fashion.
    In *implicit* mode `einsum` computes these values.

    In *explicit* mode, `einsum` provides further flexibility to compute
    other array operations that might not be considered classical Einstein
    summation operations, by disabling, or forcing summation over specified
...
        return out
    else:
        return asanyarray(operands[0], order=output_order)
File:      ~/miniconda3/envs/cvi/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py
Type:      function
```

With a url to the file location which will open up within vscode.